# How to compare and view three table in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:

1st is month

```
id  date        days
1   2015-06-01  Monday
2   2015-06-02  Tuesday
3   2015-06-03  Wednesday
4   2015-06-04  Thursday
5   2015-06-05  Friday
6   2015-06-06  Saturday
7   2015-06-07  Sunday
```

2nd is  attend

```
id  user_name   date    checkin
1   ali     2015-06-01  10:43:17
2   ali     2015-06-03  10:22:39
3   ali     2015-06-04  13:36:52
4   ali     2015-06-05  14:36:52
```

3rd is  attendout

```
id  user_name   date    checkout
1   ali     2015-06-01  05:03:17
2   ali     2015-06-03  06:00:39
3   ali     2015-06-04  06:36:02
4   ali     2015-06-05  06:06:02
```

and I want result like this:

```
username  date      checkin   checkout  day

ali     2015-06-01  10:43:17  05:03:17  Monday
        2015-06-02                      Tuesday
ali     2015-06-03  10:22:39  06:00:39  Wednesday
ali     2015-06-04  13:36:52  06:36:02  Thursday
ali     2015-06-05  14:36:52  06:06:02  Friday
        2015-06-05                      Saturday
        2015-06-05                      Sunday
```

how can I show result like this?

I am using this query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM attend 
WHERE user_name='ali' 
AND date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-07'  
Order by date
```

Comment: whats the relationships between the tables? primary keys etc? youll need a join query.  Also, dont reference the user by username, use their id.  Aim to have as little text in the database as possible.

Comment: You need a JOIN query. Also, you really don't need to store the days of the week in a separate table; PHP and MySQL each have functions that enable you to calculate that on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select t3.user_name, t3.date, t2.checkin, t3.checkout, t1.day 
from 3rd_table  as t3
inner join 2nd_table as t2 on t2.date = t3.date and t2.user_name = t3.user_name
inner join 1st_table as t1 on t1.date = t3.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this..

```
select * from month as m
left join attend as a where m.date = a.date
left join attendout as o where m.date = o.date
where a.user_name = 'ali'
    and ... // conditions you want on..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM month

INNER JOIN attend

ON month.id = attend.id

INNER JOIN attendout

ON attend.id = attendout.id;
```